# Linq to Sql join with select

Tags: sql, linq

I'm trying to create Linq which perform the same join as the SQL below:

```
select *
    from Table1
        inner join Table2 on Table1.ID = (select ID from Table2 where ID= 281026)
```

**(I know it doesn't make sense to do it this way, but I just want to know if the principle behind the join is possible)**

The Linq I have so far:

```
from t1 in ctxt.Table1
     join t2 in ctxt.Table2
         on t1.ID equals new { ID = (from t2a in ctxt.Table2
                                     where t2a.ID == 281026 
                                     select t2a.ID) }
select t1;
```

However the error i get is:

```
The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.
```

Both t1.ID and t2a.ID are integers.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you join t2 when you ultimately select only t1?

Comment: Please re-read my question, I state that the sql doesn't make sense.  Its just the principle behind the join (i.e. having a subselect in a join) that I'm interested in

Answer (score 0):

```
                                 from t2a in ctxt.Table2
                                 where t2a.ID == 281026 
                                 select t2a.ID
```

What's the point of doing this? This subquery will always return 281026, if it returns anything...

Your query is equivalent to this:

```
 from t1 in ctxt.Table1
 join t2 in ctxt.Table2
     on t1.ID equals t2.ID
 where t2.ID == 281026
 select t1;
```

Comment: "...I know it doesn't make sense to do it this way, but I just want to know if the principle behind the join is possible" i.e. having a subselect in a join

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
from t1 in ctxt.Table1
join t2 in ctxt.Table2 on t1.ID equals 
    (from t2a in ctxt.Table2 
    where t2a.ID == 281026 
    select t2a.ID)
select t1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this code errors with 't1 is not in scope on the left side of equals'.  When I swap them around I get the original error again ('The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect...)
'